# interactive report with dynamic sql statement

Tags: oracle, plsql, report, oracle-apex, interactive

I'm trying to generate an Interactive-Report in Apex with a SQL-Statement which lies in a page item (:P10_SQL), for example: select 1 from dual.

```
declare
 l_sql VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR); 
Begin
select V('P10_SQL') into l_sql from dual;
return l_sql;
End;
```

The Report has the type PL/SQL Function Body returning SQL Query.
Apex shows an error
ORA-20999: WWV_FLOW_EXEC.NULL_QUERY_RETURNED_BY_FUNCTION

Somebody gets an idea?

Comment: Does the item `P10_SQL` have a value in it? and why not just do `return v('P10_SQL');` or even `return :P10_SQL;`?

Comment: It may be helpful to try `return nvl(:P10_SQL, 'select ''no value'' as col_header from dual');` while debugging the issue

Comment: I also tried with v('P10_SQL') and :P10_SQL without success. The page item has a value in it. It hat not the source database column but gets the calculated value pasted from another page item.

Comment: How are you sure that the P10_SQL has a value in it? If you display P10_SQL on the page, does the query appear?

Comment: Yes, the page item is not hidden so I cann see the value. When i copy the value and execute in the sql developer it runs fine and returns result.

Comment: In the **Source** region of `P10_SQL`, what is **Maintain Session State** set to? If it is **Per Request (Memory Only)** you may need to change it.

Comment: I suppose because the item is only calculated on the fly and so apex probably could not see the value in it. The error results from a null value item.

Comment: You should never use the V() function in your app. That function is meant for database objects that do not exist in the context of an apex session - it's a lot slower than just referencing the app as a bind variable (use :P10_SQL instead of V('P10_SQL').

Comment: Also note that you don't need a query here - you're in PL/SQL, you can refer directly to `:P10_SQL` (or call the `v()` function if necessary) without selecting from dual.

Comment: Ultimately the right answer is that your error is being returned at *design time*, not at *run time*, and this is because the APEX builder environment must run your code in order to determine what columns are in the IR. Therefore all your application items will be null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apex acts kind of *crazy* as it doesn't always want to accept code I write (which is perfectly valid), saying that function doesn't return anything. Oh well.

Therefore, my function that returns SQL query was written in stages. The following bullets represents attempts I made; all of them are OK. The final version - the one that runs right now is as simple as `return :P77_SQL;` (I'm on page `77`)

- ```
  return 'select dummy from dual'
  ```
- ```
  declare
    l_str varchar2(4000);
  begin
    l_str := case when :P77_SQL is null then 'select dummy from dual'
                  else :P77_SQL
             end;
    return l_str;
  end;
  ```
- ```
  return :P77_SQL;
  ```

However: you can't use interactive report, has to be a **classic report** because not all tables you'll have as a source will have the same column names (unless you use aliases and match number and datatypes, which is rather complicated).

But, if you use a classic report, then turn "Use generic column names" on and set desired number of generic columns (I set it to 10; you'll know what to do in your case).

My `P77_SQL` text item submits the page when I press `ENTER`, which causes the report to refresh.

A few examples:

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is expected, not crazy - when you edit the IR in the APEX builder environment, it must run the query in order to determine the column list - but at that point there *is no user session* so `P10_SQL` by definition is `null` so the function is not returning a valid SQL query. As you pointed out, you need to provide APEX with *something* so using `NVL` to return a default query is the right approach.

Comment: Aha. Got it. Thank you, @Jeffrey.